# Name field and FirstName & LastName for classic email templates

Tags: email, data, classic

I've just noticed that the merge field for classic email templates for 
Opportunity Owner or Account Owner is something like {!Opportunity.OwnerFullName} and but the FullName field is not available to be referenced in a formula field so this makes me ask the following questions.

Is the FullName a compound data type field?
Is it that you cannot reference compound data type fields in a formula?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `FullName` is a compound field, which is why you can't ordinarily use it in formulas. The classic email template has "hacks" in it that allow it to merge certain types of data that are not normally available in formulas, but are obviously nevertheless useful. For example, the `{!Case.CaseLink}` merge field (if I recall correctly) to get the Salesforce URL for the current case, even though no such field actually exists.

Comment: one person's "hacks" is another person's "convenience features" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something very similar with Case - Please contact {!Case.OwnerFullName} in the Building and Planning Department But it's not retrieving the value in the email. can someone help